# Does luminous efficacy differ between direct and reflected sunlight?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, reflection, infrared-radiation, luminosity

With the total visible light flux being equal does reflected sunlight (by the sky, environment or shading/light redirecting surfaces) have a smaller total energy per luminous flux and therefore resulting heat gain than direct sunlight? Possibly caused by a larger luminous efficacy, i.e. more visible em radiation compared to uv and infrared, i.e. "cooler" light.

Comment: Short answer: yes, because the reflectance is not spectrally uniform.  Neither is the absorptance, which leads to black-body emittance which will have a different spectral shape than the incoming solar irradiance.

Comment: Thank you! Does this mean that most (those present in building environment and sky) materials are better at reflecting visible light and worse at reflecting uv and infrared light (i.e. absorbing infrared more than visible light)? Do you by any chance also know if these differences in reflecting capabilities at different wavelengths are known for different materials?